# React Hook Form, Zod, input.datetime-local Not working together for me

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, zod

I have a scheme such as this:

```js
const FormSchema = z.object({
  title: z.string().nonempty('A Title is required'),
  body: z.string().nonempty('A Message Body is required'),
  goTime: z.string().datetime()  //also tried .date()
})
```

I'd like to use an input with datetime-local to control editing this field. but nothing I do seems to get the schema. the validation, and the picker to be happy with each other.

```js
    const {
      register,
      handleSubmit,
      watch,
      formState: { errors }
    } = useForm<Inputs>({
      defaultValues: {
        title: title, //this is a string
        body: body || '', //this is a string?
        goTime: goTime?.toISOString().slice(0,16)  //this is the datetime field.
      }
    })
```

The input itself i've tried numerous options with

```js
              <input
                type="datetime-local"
                // defaultValue={goTime?.toISOString().slice(0,16)}
                {...register('goTime', {
                  setValueAs: (v) => new Date(v).toISOString().slice(0,16)
                })}
              />
              {errors.goTime?.message && (
                <p className='text-sm text-red-400'>{errors.goTime.message}</p>
              )}
```

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a working example of all this?  starting with an existing object. using that objects timestamp field to set the default value of the input element, and then using whatever is selected from that input element to save back to the DB after passing the validation.

Comment: Have you tried Zod coercion. ```goTime: z.coerce.date();```?